# If condition in shell script with multiple conditions including check for null strings

Tags: shell, variables, if-statement, null

What is wrong with the below syntax, I keep getting [: too many arguments

All the variables are strings, also I have introduced `var3` and `str3`, two make sure we are not comparing two null values, is there any other better option to deal with it

```
if [ "$var1" = "$var2" = "$var3" && "$str1" = "$str2" = "$str3" ]
then
echo " something"
elif [ "$var1" = "$var2" = "$var3"]
then
echo something else
elif [ "$str1" = "str2" = "str3" ]
then
echo something else
else
exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot do `a = b = c` check in a test (`[...]`)
2. You cannot use `&&, ||` in `[...]` test, instead, use `-a (and)  -o (or)`

so fix your codes as something like:

```
if [ "$a" = "$b" -a "$a" = "$c" -a "$d" = "$x" ]; then
...
```

If you want to use `&&, ||` you could use `[[...]]` condition expression evaluation, which is **bash** built-in

Comment: i tried if ( [ "$var1" = "$var2" = "$var3" ] -a ["$str1" = "$str2" = "$str3" ] ) but it is not working same error

Comment: @user3785023 I don't know if you have read my answer. do a `man test` and you will see

Comment: If there is no such option of doing x=y=z then is there any way to check if x and y are not null and then we do x=y. I tried something like this with no luck if [ -n "$a" -a -n"$b" -a $a -eq $b ]

Comment: @user3785023 have you read the man page? the `-eq` is for integer

Comment: like I said, I tried this statement, [ -n "$a" -a -n"$b" -a $a -eq $b ], not sure if it is a syntax issue.